# SAS - SQL PROC with INTO RANGED VARS OPTIONS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Iam having a code problem, that i couldn't find the solution yet, and already lost many hours reading articles and posts.
Iam getting a "ERROR: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ',', :, FROM, NOTRIM." on my SEPARATED BY... after my ranged var col1-.
Side note, this proc are inside a macro.

```
proc sql noprint;
  select libname, memname, name
  into: lib1-, tab1-, col1- SEPARATED BY ","
  from dictionary.columns
  where upcase(libname)='LIB_X' 
quit;
```

I know that if i just have it alone in my INTO statment it works fine, but when i add the libname and memname it just crash.
The final ideia was getting 3 ranged vars, one with the libname, other with table, and the final one with all column names separated with ","
Further on i will use this to calculate md5 over each (table/row).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using conflicting options for the destination of the NAME variable values.

For LIBNAME and MEMNAME you are telling PROC SQL to create a series of macro variables.  But for NAME you started to do that also, but then you added the SEPARATED BY clause which is designed for storing all of the values into ONE macro variable.

Either remove the SEPARATED BY clause to generate multiple macro variables.

Or remove the hyphen after the macro variable name to generate one macro variable with a comma delimited list of values.

But neither method makes any sense if you are pulling the list of variables from MULTIPLE datasets.

Would be much easier to just have the data in a dataset. You could then use the dataset to generate the MD5() function calls.  No need for macro variables.

If you must generate those wallpaper macro variables then use a DATA step to do it.

```
data contents;
  ds_number + 1;
do until (last.memname);
  set sashelp.vcolumn;
  where libname='LIB_X';
  by libname memname varnum;
  length varlist $3000 ;
  varlist=catx(',',varlist,name);
end;
  call symputx(cats('lib',ds_number),libname);
  call symputx(cats('tab',ds_number),memname);
  call symputx(cats('col',ds_number),varlist);
  keep ds_number libname memname varnum varlist;
run;
```

Example output:

[image]

Comment: Wow, tks Tom for all references and solution. You right ofc. :)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot ':' before each list.

```
proc sql noprint;
  select libname, memname, name
  into :lib1-, :tab1-, :col1- 
  from dictionary.columns
quit;
```

And your separated by ',' is completely unnecessary. You defined macro variables lib1, lib2, lib3,... so each will get one value. Not that saving everything from dictionary.colums into a single variable is advisable. You can easily exceed the maximum length.

Comment: Yes i did and noticed that after posting, :) tks anyway Negdo!